# Choosing random.method in R's plm

Tags: r, panel-data, plm

When it comes to estimating a Random Effects model using R’s plm package, one has a number of options under random.method. Specifically, random.method can be set to equal to "swar", "amemiya", "walhus" , or "nerlove" which corresponds to the following articles respectively.

·         Swamy, P.A.V.B. and Arora, S.S. (1972) The exact finite sample properties of the estimators of coefficients in the error components regression models, Econometrica, 40(2), pp. 261–275.

·         Amemiya, T. (1971) The estimation of the variances in a variance–components model, International Economic Review, 12(1), pp. 1–13.

·         Wallace, T.D. and Hussain, A. (1969) The use of error components models in combining cross section with time series data, Econometrica, 37(1), pp. 55–72.

·         Nerlove, M. (1971) Further evidence on the estimation of dynamic economic relations from a time series of cross sections, Econometrica, 39(2), pp. 359–382.

Suppose there are no computational issues when using any of these options for a given RE model, my question is what are the practical considerations when it comes to choosing the most appropriate option?

The plm vignette https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/vignettes/plm.pdf does not evaluate the merits or otherwise of the different options (pp. 13-14) and the original articles are too technical for me to compare and contrast each option. Thanks.